# Linear vector bundles over $\mathbb{P}GL_{n}(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-bundles

$\mathbb{P}GL_{n}$ is homotopy equivalent to the compact group $\mathbb{P}U_{n}$, whose $\mathbb{Z}/p$-cohomology are known:

[What is the integral cohomology of $\mathrm{PGL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ as a space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2371487/what-is-the-integral-cohomology-of-mathrmpgl-n-mathbbc-as-a-space)

In particular, $H^2(PU(n);\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}/p$.

Consider a linear vector bundle $\eta\to\mathbb{P}GL_{n}=\mathbb{P}GL_{n}(\mathbb{C})$, whose fiber over the point $[A]\in\mathbb{P}GL_{n}$, $A=(a_{j,k})\in GL_{n}(\mathbb{C})$, is the complex line consisting of matrices $\lambda\cdot A=(\lambda\cdot a_{j,k})$, $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$. What is the Chern class $c_{1}(\eta)$ of it? Is it non-trivial?

Similar questions for the inverse $\eta^{-1}$ (with fiber $\lambda\cdot A^{-1}$ over $[A]$), transposed $\eta^t$ (with fiber $\lambda\cdot A^t$ over $[A]$).

As is explained in the link, there is a principal $U(n)$-bundle $PU(n)\to\mathbb{C} P^{\infty}$. Is there any explicit description of the corresponding linear vector bundle over $PU(n)$?

Comment: Your bundle $\eta$ is the canonical quotient $Gl(\mathbb{C}^n)\rightarrow PGl(\mathbb{C}^n)$, and is thus non-trivial and classified by a generator of $H^2(PGl(\mathbb{C}^n);\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}_p$ (the fibre of the projection is the diagonal circle group $S^1\cdot I_n$, so the projection classifies to $BS^1\simeq K(\mathbb{Z},2)$).

Comment: You can check that the class is correct by studying the Serre spectral sequence. Although here this is made easier: you have $H^2PU_n\cong Ext(H_1PU_n,\mathbb{Z})$, so by naturality you can figure out what is going on by studying the induced maps on $H_1PU_n$, and by Hurewicz you just need to check $\pi_1PU_n$. Once you are happy that the diagonal inclusion $\Delta:S^1\rightarrow U_n$ induces multiplication by $n$ you get the result.